# How can I preserve Subversion commit messages across merges?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, merge

Is there any Subversion that can create a commit message containing a list of all the commit messages used in a merge?

Our problem is that we tend to lose all the good history information for changes performed on branches once they are merged.  Usually instead of a detailed list of fixes performed on the branch we're left with a message saying "merged branch-1.1.2 899-921", the developers then have to determine which branch and change to look at for more detailed info, a tedious task.

Is there a way to avoid this? What are your strategies for preserving commit info and history between merges.

Comment: I feel like `git` is the answer to this question.  It's been years since I asked this question and the idea of SVN now makes me shudder.

Answer (score 2):

The way we typically handle this is with svn log of the branch.  If you go to the branch, then type

```
svn log --stop-on-copy
```

you'll get a list of every commit message for that branch, back to when the branch was formed.  The stop-on-copy flag tells svn not to continue to before the branch was formed.

We also use post-commit hook to email all commits to a particular group of interested parties.  If you include there a public mail folder, then the history can exist for eternity, or until you delete the mail archive.

More on post-commit hooks in [the svn book](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsvnbook.red-bean.com%2F&ei=sLNiTMOBIIr2tgO3lNWHCA&usg=AFQjCNE_sdrUnnHEu7cewd1oZwSjHjWJmg).

Answer (score 1):

You know the -g option on command line?

```
svn log -g ^/trunk
```

which will print all log messages which have been made on the branch as well. More convinient you can take a look on the trunk via TortoiseSVN ...look better.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SVN client as Tortoise SVN you may just check the checkbox 'Indclude merged revision'